# Why isn't while loop function working here and giving me error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
row1=['a ','b ','c ']
row2=[' d',' e','f ']
row3=['g ','h ',' i']


def myfunc():
    a=' '
    while a not in (list(range(1,10))):
        a=int(input('Enter a  number between 1 to 9'))

        if a==1:
            return row1[0]
        elif a==2:
            return row1[1]
        elif a==3:
            return row1[2]
        elif a==4:
            return row2[0]
        elif a==5:
            return row2[1]
        elif a==6:
            return row2[2]
        elif a==7:
            return row3[0]
        elif a==8:
            return row3[1]
        elif a==9:
            return row3[2]
```

Here it's fine when I type numbers(1-9), but when I type something which is not correct, I expect my statement to repeat till, it receives correctly. But that isn't happening. It is showing error.

Comment: Hey, this is  copy , pasted, that could be the reason, it went like that

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your use is going to enter something besides numbers as input, so you will get an error when `int` is evaluated. You should use a `try/except` block as follows:

```py
row1=['a ','b ','c ']
row2=[' d',' e','f ']
row3=['g ','h ',' i']


def myfunc():
    a=' '

    while a not in (list(range(1,10))):
        try:
            a=int(input('Enter a  number between 1 to 9'))
        except ValueError:
            continue

        if a==1:
            return row1[0]
        elif a==2:
            return row1[1]
        elif a==3:
            return row1[2]
        elif a==4:
            return row2[0]
        elif a==5:
            return row2[1]
        elif a==6:
            return row2[2]
        elif a==7:
            return row3[0]
        elif a==8:
            return row3[1]
        elif a==9:
            return row3[2]
```

This way, when the user enters a string that cannot be converted to an int, the exception raised does not terminate your program.

Comment: @AshPro-grammar -- if this answer solved your problem, say 'thank you' and let others know, in case they have a similar question, by accepting the answer.  Click the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler if you use an explicit `continue` statement and a little bit of modular arithmetic

```
def myfunc():
    
    while True:
        
        a=int(input('Enter a  number between 1 to 9'))
        if a not in range(1,10):
            continue

        # E.g., divmod(5-1, 3) == 1, 1
        row, index = divmod(a-1, 3)

        # select the row
        if row == 0:
            row = row1
        elif row == 1:
            row = row2
        else:
            row = row3

        # return the element of the selected row
        return row[index]
```

Comment: this will work as long as the input the user enters is a number, what if he enters `"abcd"`? The program will crash.

Comment: The original program would crash too; I didn't want to introduce a change that wasn't related to the switch-like behavior, but a correct approach is indeed to get the input with `a = input(...)`, then isolate `a = int(a)` inside a `try` statement and use `continue` to handle the possible `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that you try to parse a String to a Int. But that can fail, so `int()` throws an error. You can catch that error and `continue` to get the next input. That should do the job. And your indentation is wrong(that is probably a copy and paste error)

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet.

```
row1=['a ','b ','c ']
row2=[' d',' e','f ']
row3=['g ','h ',' i']

def myfunc():
    a=0
    while not (1<=a<=9):
        try:
            a=int(input('Enter a  number between 1 to 9: '))
        except ValueError as e:
            print ("Illegal entry.")
    r,i=divmod(a-1)
    return [row1,row2,row3][r][i]
```